# How to get Java thread dump in EC2 Amazon : No jstack found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are experience 100% CPU usage issue after the server runs for 20-30mins. We are trying to troubleshoot.

I have read that we can use `jstack` to generate dump of high cpu thread.

However in Amazon ami jstack is not installed.

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.5.1.2.45.amzn1-x86_64 u65-b17)
```

Is there a way I can install jstack without reinstalling oracle build?
Also is there any other solution to get dump?

Comment: Is JDK (not JRE) available on the ec2 instance? jStack comes with the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Try following command:

```
kill -quit <java process id>
```

The threads stackthreadses should be appended to default output. 
More information available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/matrix6-unix-137789.html)

Comment: The link you posted is dead.

Answer (score 0):

`jstack` comes with the Amazon Corretto development tools, which can be installed on an EC2 instance with `yum`.

You can search what version is available via:

```
sudo yum search amazon-corretto-devel
```

At time of writing, this returned for me `java-17-amazon-corretto-devel.x86_64 : Amazon Corretto 17 development tools`

Then, to install it, run:

```
sudo yum install java-17-amazon-corretto-devel.x86_64
```

After that, `jstack` should be directly usable (the executable being `/usr/bin/jstack`)